# Countdown timer with GUI using SwingWorker - not updating properly

Tags: java, swingworker

i'm trying to make a countdown timer using swingworker, problem is when seconds get to zero, programs sets them back to 60 and deducts one.I did make the program without GUI and it works just perfect, but using swingworker my timer looks like this

1: 0: 2
1: 0: 1
0: 59: 60

which is kinda wrong and should be
1: 0: 1
1: 0: 0
0: 59: 59

Both of my class lie on the same logic.I guess it has something to do with sending the whole Time object to the 'process' but i just can't explain it to myself.

doInBackground() method :

```
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Integer hours = Integer.parseInt(hoursField.getText());
            Integer minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutesField.getText());
            Integer seconds = Integer.parseInt(secondsField.getText());

            Time time = new Time(hours, minutes, seconds);

            if(minutes < 59 & seconds < 59) {               
                if(hours >=0 & minutes >=0 & seconds >=0) {
                    boolean count = true;
                    while(count) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Chronometer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                        }
                        time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() - 1);
                        publish(time);
                        if(time.getHours() == 0 & time.getMinutes() == 0 & time.getSeconds() == 0) {
                            count = false;
                        }
                        if(time.getSeconds() == 0) {
                            time.setSeconds(60);
                            if(time.getMinutes() != 0) {
                                time.setMinutes((time.getMinutes() - 1));
                            }else if(time.getMinutes() == 0) {
                                time.setHours((time.getHours() - 1));
                                if(time.getHours() >= 0) {
                                    time.setMinutes(59);
                                }                                    
                                if(time.getHours() < 0) {
                                    time.setHours(0);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }else {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

And this is the simple java class that works on the same logic :

```
boolean count = true;
        while(count) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {

            }
            seconds--;
            System.out.println(hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds);
            if(hours == 0 & minutes == 0 & seconds == 0) {
                count = false;
            }
            if(seconds == 0) {
                seconds = 60;
                if(minutes != 0){ 
                    minutes--;
                }else if(minutes == 0) {
                    hours--;
                    if(hours >=0){
                        minutes = 59;
                    }                    
                    if(hours < 0) {
                        hours = 0;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
```

If anyone could point me my mistake, i'd be very grateful.
Thanks

Adding process method

```
public void process(List<Time> time) {
            for(Time t : time) {                    
                showField.setText(String.valueOf(t.getHours()) + ": " + String.valueOf(t.getMinutes())+ ": " + String.valueOf(t.getSeconds()));
            }
        }
```

Comment: time.setSeconds(60); should be time.setSeconds(59);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your line

```
if(time.getSeconds() == 0) time.setSeconds(60);
```

needs to be

```
if(time.getSeconds() == 0) time.setSeconds(59);
```

And invert this tow lines:

```
time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() - 1);
publish(time);
```

like this:

```
publish(time);
time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() - 1);
```

The deduction is correct but it's not showing the result because when seconds reaches cero the conditional it's executed, not showing the intermediate time.

Change this line:

```
 if(time.getSeconds() == 0)
```

for this one:

```
 if(time.getSeconds() < 0)
```

And this:

```
 if(time.getHours() == 0 & time.getMinutes() == 0 & time.getSeconds() == 0)

 if(time.getHours() == 0 & time.getMinutes() == 0 & time.getSeconds() < 0)
```

Comment: 1: 0: 2   
1: 0: 1    
0: 59: 59 Wrong output again, its not a logic problem, the program works without SwingWorker(Just a print on the console) and its okay, i guess it has something to do with sending the class Time to the process and printing goes right without deducting correctly.

Comment: 1 0 2
1 0 1
0 59 59  Still, much better but not working as intended... and i doubt  its about order of lines. I made the same program without swingworker and its method(juts printing the lines on the console) and it works just fine... that's what is confusing me... maybe when sending the object time to process and itterating through the whole List...

Comment: Finally worked, seems it was not SwingWorker, thanks for your time mate thought i left  if(time.getHours() == 0 & time.getMinutes() == 0 & time.getSeconds() == 0) so it can finish at 0 : 0 : 0 and it still works, Thanks alot !

Answer (score 1):

I did not dig at your logic, but you can achieve the same using `Calendar` which looks more simple.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    Date d = c.getTime();
    System.out.println(format.format(d)); 
    while(count) {
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, c.get(Calendar.SECOND)-1); //decrement 1 second at a time
        d = c.getTime();
        System.out.println(format.format(d)); 
        Thread.sleep(1000); //Pause for a second between each print
    }
```

I have used `SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")` for simplicity. If you need different fields of time, then you can use `Calendar.get(..)` method to get the same

Comment: I'm getting the input from a Form where you type in the values in text fields, then the program should start counting down till it gets to zero, i did not post all of my program.

Comment: `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` are your input right?.. if you see in the  line 2,3,4 i am using the same